# How can I set up devise_saml_authenticatable with multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5, activeadmin, simplesamlphp

I'm designing a rails 5 app with two user models; user and admin_user (the default for active_admin). I am using devise for authentication. Originally I was using database-authenticatable, but now I need implement SSO through saml.
I found and successfully set up the devise_saml_authenticatable gem for one model (users) but I am not sure where to start with setting it up with my other model (active_admin admin_users). I am using simpleSamlPhp as my identity provider locally.

Here is my config for devise in devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config| ...

config.saml_configure do |settings|

      settings.assertion_consumer_service_url     = "http://localhost:3000/users/saml/auth"
      settings.assertion_consumer_service_binding = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
      settings.name_identifier_format             = "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient"
      settings.issuer                             = "http://localhost:3000/saml/metadata"
      settings.authn_context                      = ""

      settings.idp_slo_target_url                 = "http://simplesaml.dev/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php"


      settings.idp_sso_target_url                 = "http://simplesaml.dev/saml2/idp/SSOService.php"

      settings.idp_cert                           = <<-CERT.chomp
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

My-Certificate-Here

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
      CERT
    end
end
```

The problem is that rails will direct the log in Url: localhost:3000/users/saml/sign_in to http://localhost:3000/users/saml/auth
but direct the admin log in localhost:3000/users/saml/sign_in to the same url when signing in through the admin login page.

routes.rb

```
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
  devise_for :users
```

My models:

admin_user.rb

```
class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord
  devise  :saml_authenticatable
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise  :saml_authenticatable
end
```

Comment: I didn't know ActiveAdmin had deep integration with devise like that. What does `devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config` do exactly?

Taking ActiveAdmin out of the picture, I'd say that all you'd need is the configure the routes separately using `devise_for` each user type, and use `authenticate_user!` and `authenticate_admin_user!` appropriately.